# Show that $T$ has a fixed point $z_{0}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $T$ be a Mobius transformation with a periodic orbit $ O=\{ z_{1},\ldots , z_{q} \}$ of period $q\ge2$. i.e the $z_{i}$'s are distinct and  $z_{1}\mapsto T(z_{1})=z_{2}\mapsto T(z_{2})=z_{3}\mapsto .....\mapsto T(z_{q-1})=z_{q}\mapsto T(z_{q})=z_{1}$. Show that $T$ has a fixed point $z_{0}$ such that $T'(z_{0})$ is a premitive $q-th$ root of unity.

Comment: What do you know about fixed points of Möbius transformations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of this problem uses a case analysis, based on the classification of Mobius transformation into three types: loxodromic, parabolic, elliptic.

Let's write $T(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ where $ad-bc=1$, $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$.

- If $|a+d| > 2$ then $T$ is loxodromic, and is conjugate to a similarity, of the form $z \mapsto Az$ where $|A| > 1$. In this case $T$ has exactly two periodic points, each of which is fixed. So this case is ruled out.
- If $|a+d|=2$ then there are two subcases: either $T$ is the identity and every point is fixed; or $T$ is parabolic, $T$ is conjugate to a translation of the form $z \mapsto z+B$, so $T$ has a unique periodic point and that point is fixed. Thus both subcases are ruled out.
- If $|a+d|<2$ then $T$ is elliptic, and is conjugate to something of the form $z \mapsto Az$ where $|A|=1$. This is the operative case for your question. If $A$ is a primitive $q^{th}$ root of unity then every orbit except for the fixed points $0,\infty$ is periodic of period $q$, and so your conclusion is true. If $A$ is not a primitive $q^{th}$ root of unity for any $q$ then every orbit except $0,\infty$ has infinite orbit.

Comment: Why is these conditions on $|a+d|$ true?

Comment: @user152715: Whatever $a$ and $d$ are, one of those three conditions is true. That's how a case analysis proof works.

Comment: Sorry I haven't put my question in the right way. My question was why corresponding to that condition $z\mapsto Az$, $z\mapsto Z+B$ etc true? Can you please describe..

Comment: @user152715: You can find this in most explanations of Mobius transformations, such as the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_transformation#Classification